# Ampache nginx config

Tags: nginx

Does anyone have a working config? I cannot get mine to work. I've copied the one from the ampache git and changed what I think I should but I cannot successfully restart nginx. I know nginx is working with the default file but not with this? Any ideas?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

    server_name mymedia.com;
    charset utf-8;

    # Logging, error_log mode [notice] is necessary for rewrite_log on,
    # (very usefull if rewrite rules do not work as expected)

         error_log       /var/log/ampache/error.log; # notice;
       # access_log      /var/log/ampache/access.log;
       # rewrite_log     on;

    # only optional for ssl encryption enabled: Path to certificate/key

        # ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt;
        # ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.key;

    root /var/www/ampache;
    index index.php;

    # Somebody said this helps, in my setup it doesn't prevent temporary saving in files
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    # Rewrite rule for Subsonic backend
    if ( !-d $request_filename ) {
        rewrite ^/rest/(.*).view$ /rest/index.php?action=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/rest/fake/(.+)$ /play/$1 last;
    }

    # Rewrite rule for Channels
    if (!-d $request_filename){
      rewrite ^/channel/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /channel/index.php?channel=$1&target=$2 last;
    }

    # Beautiful URL Rewriting
        rewrite ^/play/ssid/(\w+)/type/(\w+)/oid/([0-9]+)/uid/([0-9]+)/name/(.*)$ /play/index.php?ssid=$1&type=$2&oid=$3&uid=$4&name=$5 last;
        rewrite ^/play/ssid/(\w+)/type/(\w+)/oid/([0-9]+)/uid/([0-9]+)/client/(.*)/noscrobble/([0-1])/name/(.*)$ /play/index.php?ssid=$1&type=$2&oid=$3&uid=$4&client=$5&noscrobble=$6&name=$7 last;
        rewrite ^/play/ssid/(.*)/type/(.*)/oid/([0-9]+)/uid/([0-9]+)/client/(.*)/noscrobble/([0-1])/player/(.*)/name/(.*)$ /play/index.php?ssid=$1&type=$2&oid=$3&uid=$4&client=$5&noscrobble=$6&player=$7&name=$8 last;
        rewrite ^/play/ssid/(.*)/type/(.*)/oid/([0-9]+)/uid/([0-9]+)/client/(.*)/noscrobble/([0-1])/transcode_to/(w+)/bitrate/([0-9]+)/player/(.*)/name/(.*)$ /play/index.php?ssid=$1&type=$2&oid=$3&uid=$4&client=$5&noscrobble=$6&transcode_to=$7&bitrate=$8&player=$9&name=$10 last;

    # the following line was needed for me to get downloads of single songs to work
        rewrite ^/play/ssid/(.*)/type/(.*)/oid/([0-9]+)/uid/([0-9]+)/action/(.*)/name/(.*)$ /play/index.php?ssid=$1&type=$2&oid=$3&uid=$4action=$5&name=$6 last;
        location /play {
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/play/art/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/thumb([0-9]*)\.([a-z]+)$ /image.php?object_type=$2&object_id=$3&auth=$1;
                break;
                }

        rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /play/$3?$1=$2;
        rewrite ^/(/[^/]+|[^/]+/|/?)$ /play/index.php last;
        break;
        }

   location /rest {
      limit_except GET POST {
         deny all;
      }
   }

   location ^~ /bin/ {
      deny all;
      return 403;
   }

   location ^~ /config/ {
      deny all;
      return 403;
   }

   location / {
      limit_except GET POST HEAD{
         deny all;
      }
   }

   location ~ ^/.*.php {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

    # sets the timeout for requests in [s] , 60s are normally enough
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    # has to be set to on if encryption (https) is used:
        # fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    # chose as your php-fpm is configured to listen on
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000/;
   }

   # Rewrite rule for WebSocket
   location /ws {
        rewrite ^/ws/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8100/;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was solved with creating the error log folder `/var/log/ampache/`.
For further troubelshooting (if needed) use `sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t`, this gives you more verbose error messages.
Good luck!